# Rspec Does Not Recognize Rails's content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have a Rails (4.2) helper that I am trying to unit test with Rspec 3.

```
# app/helpers/nav_helper.rb
module NavHelper
  def nav_link(body, url, li_class: "", html: {})
    li_class += current_page?(url) ? " active" : ""

    content_tag(:li, class: li_class) do
      link_to(body, url, html)
    end
  end
end

# spec/helpers/nav_helper_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe NavHelper do
  describe "#nav_link" do
    it "creates a correctly formatted link" do
      link = nav_link("test", "www.example.com/testing")
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This throws the following error when I run the test:

```
 Failure/Error: link = nav_link("test", "www.example.com/testing")
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `content_tag' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::NavHelper::NavLink:0x007fe44b98fee0>
 # ./app/helpers/nav_helper.rb:5:in `nav_link'
```

It seems like the Rails helpers aren't available, but I'm not sure how to include them. Regardless, how can I test a helper method that uses `content_tag`?

**Update**

Adding `include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` throws the following error

```
uninitialized constant ActionView (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the leading line of my spec. I changed `require 'spec_helper'` to `require 'rails_helper'` and everything works as expected.

Not the first time that's bitten me, but it was the hardest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the helper that contains the `content_tag` method in your `NavHelper` (in this case, [`TagHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)):

```
module NavHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  # ...
end
```

It's a good idea to include only the helpers that you need to make things work, as it makes it clear which parts of Rails/ActionView you're using in your helper.

**EDIT**: Why is this necessary?

When you're testing the helper, you're testing it in isolation from the rest of Rails. That's why RSpec is complaining about the method not being available - it literally isn't there!

Comment: This throws the error `uninitialized constant NavHelper::ActionView (NameError)`, whether I include it in the module as you suggested or in the test itself.

Comment: Does adding `::` in front of `ActionView` fix that?

Comment: It changes it. Now it says: `uninitialized constant ActionView`. Sorry for my delayed responses!